# Wrong position of images inside ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-adapter, universal-image-loader

I'm using an `ArrayAdapter` for filling a `ListView`.

The code I used for the `getView` is the following:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = convertView;
    if(rowView ==null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);         
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout_member, parent, false);
        }
    TextView tvName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
    TextView tvSurname = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label1);
    ImageView ivPhoto = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);        

    setRow(tvName ,tvSurname ,ivPhoto,name[position],surname[position],pics[position],); // name, surname and pics are the array of String passed to the adapter.

    return rowView;
}

private void setRow(TextView tv1, TextView tv2, ImageView iv, String name, String surname, String photo){
    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.sagoma);
    tv1.setText(String.valueOf(name));
    tv2.setText(String.valueOf(surname)); //la quantità la devo prendere da un array di 
    if(photo!=null)
        imageLoader.displayImage(basePath+photo, iv, options);
      }
```

This works fine,but i have following problem:
Since I'm using `convertView`, the views are recycled, so when I scroll up and down, can happen that some images are pushed in wrong row of my `ListView`, especially when I scroll fast.

How can I avoid this problem, without sacrificing the recycling of View?

**NOTE:**

```
imageLoader.displayImage(basePath+immagine, iv, options);
```

comes from Universal image Loader library. This method calls a thread for load the image. If the image is no more required (cause scroll) the thread is stopped.

Answer (score 0):

When scrolling - by the time the image loader is ready to display your image, your image is no longer relevant - your problem is probably in the displayImage code - rather than your getView code

Comment: as I said in the note, displayImage is a method of Universal Image Loader, that use a thread for getting image from web (or disk)

Comment: check pauseOnScrollListener of that library

Comment: how would you check whether image is relevant or not?